# How can I create this graph with using rest api response value's in flutter?

Tags: flutter, graph

[image]

here is the data that is coming from databases ;

**{
"name": "Jan",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
},
{
"name": "Feb",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
},
{
"name": "Mar",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
},
{
"name": "Apr",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
},
{
"name": "May",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
},
{
"name": "Jun",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
},
{
"name": "Jul",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
},
{
"name": "Aug",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
},
{
"name": "Sep",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
},
{
"name": "Oct",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
},
{
"name": "Nov",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
},
{
"name": "Dec",
"total": 0.0,
"resolved": 0.0
}
]**

Answer (score 0):

Here,
Your response has 3 data values.

If we focus on a particular data provided.
You can create a class as follows :

```
class ApiData {
  final String name;
  final double total;
  final double resolved;
  
  ApiData({
    required this.name,
    required this.total,
    required this.resolved,
  });
}
```

Then, you can take your response and treat it as a `List<ApiData>`.

For creating a graph you need 2 co-ordinates (x, y).

Your x is the month and your y is the value.
You can represent your month as an integer.
(Jan = 1, Feb = 2 and so on)

You can represent it as a class :

```
class Coordinates {
  final int x;
  final double y;
  
  Coordinates({
    required this.x,
    required this.y,
  });
}
```

Now,
You need a way to generate a list of co-ordinates for the red graph and blue graph.

If red graph represents total tickets created and blue graph represents resolved tickets.

You can do this as follows :

Let's say that you get the response data and you convert that to a `List<ApiData>` and store it in a variable called `r`.

```
...
List<Coordinates> redGraph = r.map(
  (e) => Coordinates(x: convertToInt(e.name), y: e.total)
).toList(); 

List<Coordinates> blueGraph = r.map(
  (e) => Coordinates(x: convertToInt(e.name), y: e.resolved)
).toList(); 
...
```

Here, you need a logic called `convertToInt()`
that converts
`(Jan to 1 , Feb to 2 and so on)` {Do this yourself}

Now,
You can use `blueGraph` and `redGraph` to draw your graph.